# ActionScript 3 newbie syntax error

Tags: actionscript-3

This seems really basic, and I've done similar declarations, but I'm getting an error "1078: Label must be a simple identifier" on the line declaring my 16 Sprites.

```
var tables:Array = [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14,t15,t16];
for (i=0;i<16;i++){
tables[i]:Sprite = new Sprite();
}
```

I'm missing something, any help?

Comment: 1- What's `t1, t2, ..., t16` ?  2- You can not write `array[i]:ClassName = new ClassName` but `array[i] = new ClassName`.

Comment: What akmozo's saying is the answer.  If you want a "typed array", use a `Vector.<Sprite>`, not an `Array`.  You still wouldn't be able to say `vect[i]:ClassName = new ClassName()` though; it'd still have to be `vect[i] = new ClassName()`.  However by using a vector of type `T`, each element would be guaranteed to be of type `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ohters have already said, you cannot declare a type for an array item.
However, it is considered good practice to always add a comment describing what type are the array items:

```
var tables:Array /* of Sprites */ = [t1,t2,t3,...];
```

And obviously not mixing types in the same array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:
tables[i]:Sprite = new Sprite();

should be:
tables[i] = new Sprite();

When you get "1078: Label must be a simple identifier" - 9 times out of 10 it is because you used a colon in the wrong place or instead of a semicolon at the end of a line.